# Multiple object with one outlet

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitableview

I have a table view cell that is used in a multilingual application. I used two different `UITableViewCell` in my storyboard for right to left and left to right applications but both of these UITableViewCells are linked to one file.

I used this because I do not want to load diffrent cells when text orientation is right to left or left to right.

Suppose that we have one label into each cell. In objective c we can assign this two label into one outlet. But in swift only one of them can be assigned. When I assign one of them the other one remove

How can we do this mechanism in swift too?

Comment: did you tried the following syntax for IBOutlet?
`@IBOutlet strong var labelName: UILabel?`

Comment: this is the code of my outlet: @IBOutlet weak var insuranceName: LICustomLabel!

Comment: change the `weak` reference to `strong`...for some weird reasons it is working for me.

Comment: @HuseinBehbudiRad you will not connect two labels with same IBOutlet

Comment: why should not connect? They are actually one lable. also it is available in objective c

Comment: Connect you single CellClass with both of your cells. there you will see different IBOutlets for each cell. connect your label with its own cell's IBOutlet

Comment: @Bluewings strong is not working too

Comment: @Shoaib I want to connect this to object into one outlet. not two outlet in two diffrent files

Comment: Same I am trying to make you understand there would be one IBOutlet but ... wait I am gonna attached sample project.

Comment: see the sample code http://wikisend.com/download/291852/StackOver 2.zip

Comment: Is that working because you defined them into one file?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87773/discussion-between-shoaib-and-husein-behbudirad).

Answer (score 0):

not just make outlet of label.
use **outletCollection**.

normally set property of label is like:

- `cell.lbl.text = "Title"`

need to do with this **outletCollection** is like:

- `cell.lbls.forEach{ $0.text = "Title" }`

Answer (score -1):

I think it would be a better solution to set the textAlignment of the cell depending on the current language:

Try get the language with

```
var pre = NSLocale.preferredLanguages()[0]
```

and depending on whether it is a latin (Germanic, romanic etc. ;-) or arabic language you set

```
cell.textLabel?.textAlignment = .Left
cell.detailTextLabel?.textAlignment = .Right
```

see
[How to get current language code with Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24591167/how-to-get-current-language-code-with-swift)
and
[Swift UITableViewCell Alignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30596940/swift-uitableviewcell-alignment)

Regards
Simon

Comment: alignment is not my problem. I have two completely different views for rtl and ltr views